# Program to replace all substring in a string

Tags: c

This a program for replacing all substring with a given string in a string..but it is showing segmentation fault..pls help..

```
char s[1000]="i am a good boy,he  is a good boy";
char rep[100]="good";
char new[100]="bad";
char result[1000];
char *tmp;
int len;
char *k=s;

while(1) 
{
    tmp=strstr(k,rep);
    if(tmp==NULL)
        break;
    len=tmp-k;  
    tmp=tmp+strlen(rep);    
    strncpy(result,k,len);
    strcat(result,new); 
    k=k+len+strlen(rep);        
}
strcat(result,tmp);
puts(result);
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in C++.

Comment: It would help if you showed compilable code.  It looks like you need `int main(void) {` at the top (and `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>` too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this one:

```
void main()
{
    char s[1000]="i am a good boy,he  is a good boy";
    char rep[100]="good";
    char newstr[100]="bad";
    char result[1000] = "";
    char *tmp;
    int len;
    char *k=s;
    char *res = result;
    while(1) 
    {
        tmp=strstr(k,rep);
        if(tmp==NULL)
            break;
        len=tmp-k;  
        tmp=tmp+strlen(rep);    
        strncpy(res,k,len);
        strcat(res,newstr); 
        res += len + strlen(newstr);
        k=k+len+strlen(rep);        
    }
    if(!tmp)
        strcat(result,k);
    puts(result);   
}
```

Some notes:
1) new is a keyword, you can't name variable like this
2) you should initialize result char with "", that allow you correctly strcat'int to it
3) you should detect the place, where to strcat to result (done it with char *res pointer)

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses `strncpy()` but does not null-terminate the string, and then uses `strcat()` to append to the non-terminated string.  This is not a good idea.

Your code always copies to (the start of) `result` on each iteration, throwing away anything copied in the previous iteration.  This is not a good idea either.

Your code would also commit the 'clbuttic' mistake of matching and substituting parts of words (so 'goods' — as in 'goods train' — would become 'bads' if the code worked).

Comment: It seems that the variable `tmp` was designed to treat the issue of overwriting the result, but has no effect yet beacuse the code is unfinished.

Answer (score 1):

memcpy version.

```
char *s="i am a good boy,he  is a good boy";
char *rep="good";
char *new_word="bad";
char result[1000];
char *tmp;
int r_len= strlen(rep);
int n_len= strlen(new_word);
char *k=s;
char *r=result;

while(1){
    if(NULL==(tmp=strstr(k,rep))){
        memcpy(r, k, strchr(k, '\0') - k + 1);
        break;
    }
    r = (char*)memcpy(r, k, tmp - k) + (tmp - k);
    r = (char*)memcpy(r, new_word, n_len) + n_len;
    k = tmp + r_len;
}
puts(result);
```