# Replacing substring in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I am a very new programmer and I have been having a hard time figuring this out. I have looked online but I can't seem to find a clear answer. How do I go about replacing a desired substring by another in C?

I basically would like the user to be able to edit their string if they wanted to.

I know how to get the following:

- The index from where to start making the edit
- The length of the new substring to be added

I was wondering how do I then go about inserting the new substring and deleting the old one?

Any Help would be so appreciated

This is my code:

```
int length;
char firstString[100];
char editIndex[100];
char newString[100]; 
Char editedString[100];

printf("Enter your string: \n");
fgets(firstString, 100, stdin);

printf("Enter the word from which you would like to start editing: \n");
fgets(editIndex, 100, stdin);

printf("What substring would you like there instead?\n");
fgets(newString, 100, stdin);

length = strlen (newString);
```

This is where I get confused, I have the index from where to start the index (the first character of the word, and I know how long the edit is. I just don't know how to delete the original character(s) that were there and replace it by the new ones. I thought of using a for loop but I am not sure it would work.

This is what I would like to have as an end result:

```
printf("%s", editedString);
```

and then this printing the edit the user has made.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! If you could post what code you have so far and what you've tried to do, it will really help other users help you.

Comment: [Program to replace all substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347210/program-to-replace-all-substring-in-a-string/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop that iterates from the index of where to start making the edit and ends when the index is the length of the substring from the starting point setting the characters all the way. It needs to be careful not to overrun past the length of the original string.

Example

```
char theString[10] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
char theSubString[5] = {'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'};

for (int i = 0; i < 5, i++)
    theString[5 + i] = theSubString[i];
```

This replaces the desired substring "World" with the string "Earth"

"HelloWorld"
becomes
"HelloEarth"

Comment: Thank you so much!! It has gotten me on the right path, but for some reason it only accepts changes when the index is equal to 0 and not where would i want the change to be.  Thank you so much nonetheless!!!

Comment: Could you post your current code for changing the attay, so I can evaluate the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing here is how strings are stored in C. Strings in C are simply stored as an array of `char`s, with a terminating NULL character (`\0`). That information leads to the answer to your question, as well as a problem with what you're trying to do.

The problem is that because strings are saved as arrays, the string that you are trying to insert must be the same length as the string you are removing. Otherwise, if the new string is shorter than the old, you'll end up not fully removing the old string, and if the new string is longer than the old, you'll be overwriting other characters not included in the old string. To implement this so that the strings can be of different lengths, your code is going to have to account for the change in number of letters and shift other letters around in the word accordingly. Don't forget that if you shift letters further down the string, you also have to move the NULL character at the end and that you're not going beyond the end of the array.

The solution, though, is that because it's only an array of characters, individual characters can be accessed (and changed) simply by using array subscripts. If you can find the index of your substring, you can simply copy in your new string letter by letter.

Comment: @kirkosaur , please note that many word processors will use a linked list of strings (words / lines / x-max-length letter groups), instead of one long array. This allows for micro-management of long sections. i.e. this would allow you to replace "Hello", "World" with "Hello" "Mother" by simply linking "Hello" to the new string ("Mother") and freeing the "World" string. Each word could have a white space indicator (what comes after it? a space? a new line? nothing?) and empty words can be used for multiple white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
int delete_substring (char *str, char *substr) {
    char *loc = strstr (str, substr);  // find position of substring 
    if (!loc) return -1;               // not found 
    int sublen = strlen (substr);
    for (int i = loc - str;; i++) {
        str [i] = str [i + sublen];  // move characters left overwriting substr positions
        if (str [i] == '\0') break;  // moved the end of string char, we are done 
    }
    return loc - str; // use pointer difference to return the integer where substr found
}
```

Comment: This is effectively illegible without code formatting